# Flutter iOS app crash after startup screen in Xcode 11.1

Tags: xcode, flutter

I just upgraded Xcode to 11.1 and now my app crashes.

This is error  I see in Xcode

Can you please let me know how to fix this error

```
2019-10-09 20:52:16.569622-0400 Runner[11435:99091] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ba9f68 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff25614de9 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4757a29f -[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:] + 255
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4757a742 -[UIApplication statusBar] + 24
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff2563de07 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 317
    7   Runner                              0x000000010880238b -[FlutterStatusbarcolorPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 955
    8   Flutter                             0x00000001091284fd Flutter + 550141
    9   Flutter                             0x00000001090c1ec0 Flutter + 130752
    10  Flutter                             0x00000001090c5780 Flutter + 145280
    11  Flutter                             0x0000000109122db3 Flutter + 527795
    12  Flutter                             0x00000001090d43f1 Flutter + 205809
    13  Flutter                             0x00000001090d9742 Flutter + 227138
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0d994 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0d682 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0ccda __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b07a4e __CFRunLoopRun + 2238
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b06e66 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38346bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47578dd0 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    21  Runner                              0x000000010859a640 main + 112
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please add the dependencies or code that operating on status bar, which caused this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the plugins that you depended on. The plugin that operating on the statusBar need to be updated to the statusBarManager to work on iOS13.

Related issues:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40998
https://github.com/mchome/flutter_statusbarcolor/issues/27

Comment: Thanks.. the issue was the status plugin need to be upgraded for iOS 13

Comment: Oh... I've improved the answer.  Sorry for the first version of it. Thanks a lot for accepting it.

Comment: hi @Kevin which plugin and where to find it.